# Why does this lodash includes return true?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a csv value and need to check that one of the csv values in my array units available.

Why do I get in both cases true?

```js
let arr = [16]
let check = _.includes('14,15,16,17,18,19', arr)
console.log(check);

arr = [6]
check = _.includes('14,15,16,17,18,19', arr)
console.log(check);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I expected that only the first example would return true. How can I achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `_includes` [is](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#includes)

```
_.includes(collection, value, [fromIndex=0])
```

And in case the `collection` is a string - which it is here:

> If collection is a string, it's checked for a substring of value

And both values you're passing - `[16]` and `[6]` - when coerced to strings - exist as substrings. (`'16'` and `'6'`)

It sounds like you might want to turn the string into an array of numbers first - and check against only a single value, not an array. Eg:

```js
const inputString = '14,15,16,17,18,19';
const arrOfNumbers = JSON.parse(`[${inputString}]`);
console.log(arrOfNumbers.includes(16));
console.log(arrOfNumbers.includes(6));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Your code works good, but I have an array to pass the include function, so this/my code unfortunaly not works.

const inputString = '14,15,16,17,18,19';
    const arrOfNumbers = JSON.parse(`[${inputString}]`);
    console.log(arrOfNumbers.includes([16,14]));
    console.log(arrOfNumbers.includes([6]));

Comment: Do you want to check that all numbers in the smaller array exist in the bigger one, or that at least one exists in the bigger one, or what? Use `.every` or `.some`.

Comment: I need to check, if one or both numbers in my array in the csv value exists.

Comment: That sounds silly, Sorry. I need to check that all numbers in array exist in the csv value

Comment: `.every(num => arrOfNumbers.includes(num))`

Comment: Cool, _.every was the solution for my problem. Thanks :-)